# mysql charge query based on weight range

Tags: mysql

I have got the following table that is used to calculate a charge based on a weight range

```
Charge    Weight
1         0.5
2         1
3         2
4         5
```

I would like to calculate the charge for a box that weighs 2.5,

```
select charge from charge_table where weight > 2.5 limit 1;
```

Or should go with this option, but it duplicates data?

```
Charge    min    max
1         0      0.5
2         0.5    1
3         1      2
4         2      5
```

And then use the following query

```
select * from charge_table where min > 2.5 and max <= 2.5;
```

Whats the ideal way to setup the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first method.  The correct query is:

```
select charge
from charge_table
where weight > 2.5
order by weight desc
limit 1;
```

You would want an index on `charge_table(weight, charge)`.  An intelligent use of the index would be to look up the value `2.5`, then find the first value next to it.

With the second method, your query is correct.  It can use an index on `min`/`max`.  However, because of the inequality, the index usage may not be as efficient.  For equivalent efficiency, you can do:

```
select *
from charge_table
where min > 2.5 and max <= 2.5
limit 1;
```

Comment: I suspect the table is not very, indexing is probably not a big issue.

Comment: The table would have less than 50 entries, so indexing would not be a huge issue as per @Barmar comments

Comment: @Carlos . . . Probably not.  The data would fit on a single page in memory and a scan of the table is probably sufficient.  That said, making `min` the primary key and using `limit` in the query is probably still optimal, regardless of which structure you use.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the indexing point raised by yourself and Barmar is valid, i have added the index to option 1, the first query needs to order by asc.